# Postfix virtual_alias_maps and virtual_mailbox_maps delivery to Dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a working Postfix setup where I can deliver incoming mails to both a Dovecot mailbox, *and* forward on those mails to an external address. However, this doesn't feel right, and I'd appreciate a sanity check.

The Postfix `main.cf` includes both `virtual_alias_maps` and `virtual_mailbox_maps`. Assume that I'm handling mails for `pg@example.com`, and that

1. These emails have to be delivered to Dovecot mailbox `mbox`, and
2. These emails must also be forwarded to `pg@foo.com`

In `virtual_alias_maps` I originally had:

```
pg@example.com  pg@example.com, pg@foo.com
```

And in `virtual_mailbox_maps` I originally had:

```
pg@example.com  example.com/mbox/
```

This seemed logical to me, but didn't work. The mails are forwarded to `pg@foo.com` Ok, but Dovecot delivery fails, with a bounce. I managed to fix this by changing `virtual_alias_maps` to:

```
pg@example.com  mbox@example.com, pg@foo.com
```

And changing `virtual_mailbox_maps` to:

```
mbox@example.com  example.com/mbox/
```

I'm not really happy with this because it doesn't seem to fit in with any documentation I've found. As far as I can see, `virtual_mailbox_maps` is meant to map an *address* to a mailbox, and not a *mailbox* to a mailbox. Am I doing this the right way, or is there a better way to do this?